# Why does an acoustic guitar body amplify all notes and not just certain ones?

Tags: acoustics, string, wavelength, resonance

We all heard that acoustic guitar body acts as the amplifier of the sound created by wire plucking and strumming. This is because an acoustic guitar body is some kind of resonator.

Every resonator amplifies just certain frequencies while it inhibits all others. 
So why then when an acoustic guitar is played we hear all notes amplified and not just certain ones? Shouldn't there be some notes louder and some other notes quieter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Every resonator amplifies just certain frequencies while it inhibits all others.

This is true only for very simple resonators. The shape of the guitar body is such that it has a different size at different angles. This corresponds to different resonant frequencies. In addition, the top has a supporting bracing that is very different on different models and is critical for the sound.

Furthermore, a guitar is nor necessarily a resonator, but a converter of the mechanical energy of the strings to the acoustic energy of the air. You are absolutely correct that a strong resonance at a certain frequency would help this frequency at the expense of other frequencies and thus would be detrimental for the sound of a broad spectrum instrument. Therefore the objective of the guitar design (counter intuitively at first) is not to create, but to avoid strong resonances.

There are two parts in a guitar relevant here. One is the top made either of softer ceder for a warmer sound or harder spruce for a brighter sound (sometimes a two-layer top has both). The purpose of the top is to move air with its large area thus converting the mechanical energy of the strings to the acoustical energy of the sound. However, the top radiates both forward and back, plus the sound radiated back is out of phase with the sound radiated forward.

The second important part is the body. Historically the most popular material for the body had been the Brazilian rosewood before Brazil prohibited exporting it. Similar results are achieved with the rosewood from India, Madagascar, and other areas. Mahogany is also popular along with other wood species.

The main purpose of the body is to reflect forward (through the sound hole) the sound emitted back by the top and do it while inverting the phase, so that the sound emitted by the sound hole would be in phase with the sound emitted forward by the desk. Thus the guitar body is not a resonator, but a phase inverter very similar to common speakers with a [PORT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_reflex). Phase inversion depends on the internal dimensions of the body and is a compromise in order to optimize all frequencies equally. Although this is more important for lower frequencies (again, similarly to speakers).

The materials, shape, and bracing have been perfected by generations of guitar makers resulting in specific sound signatures. One example is the 1A model with a ceder top by Jose Romirez. Its sound is mesmerizing.

[Bass Reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_reflex)

Comment: +1 this is Countto10.  My favourite violin piece is "lark ascending" by Vaughan Williams (yeah, I'm old :) but this article might interest you re the hype over violins and their value http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/05/million-dollar-strads-fall-modern-violins-blind-sound-check

Comment: @User171879 What happened to your user name? :)

Comment: The guitarist's and luthier's term for what you call the "deck" here is *the top*. Many would say that rosewood (Brazilian or otherwise), while being the most popular body wood, is not objectively the best. It lends a classic, balanced sound, especially to the most popular body sizes and shapes. Jumbo guitars and guitarists who would like more clarity may prefer maple, and that's just one example. There are many effective tonewoods and guitar manufacturers of all sizes offer selections of different body styles and tonewoods. +1

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks, I've updated the answer. I knew it sounded a bit off :)

Comment: You have a grammatical error, *"... is is..."* around the parenthetical regarding a counterintuitive idea about avoiding resonance.

Comment: For anyone with an EE background, the purpose of a guitar body is impedance matching. The strings are a high-impedance source, and air is a low-impedance medium, so you need a transformer (the soundboard) to get much energy transfer. Or an amplifier, but then you've got an electric guitar :)

Comment: @hobbs Quite true, the top with the bridge is a transformer tuned for the most efficient energy transfer. The body is a phase inverter tuned for the same purpose. This tuning is an art. A good concert guitar sounds so much louder that the energy efficiency of a cheap plywood guitar cannot possibly be more than 10%. This is reflected in a 100-fold cost difference of course.

Comment: @safesphere re: my user name: I changed it to update my profile, (I didn't know I can't it  change back  again until mid november, silly me), no  big loss....studying for a while, I would like to give better answers on shm, TD and Stat Mech and electricity.

Comment: @hobbs I might say "mode matching" instead of impedance matching (or perhaps both). The cross section of the string is very small compared to the guitar body. The situation is similar to the flare of a brass instrument's output.